# Querying DOM in Angular2 component

Tags: angular

I need to query the DOM within an Angular2 component when it finishes loading (or rather, when the DOM is ready). More specifically, I need to find elements with a particular class, i.e. `document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')`.

The problem I keep running into is that the DOM does not seem to be ready whenever I try to query it. I have tried the following code.

```
// Within one of the Angular lifecycle hooks

let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');

let el = this._elementRef.nativeElement;
let elements = el.getElementsByClassName('myclass');

[].forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    console.log(el);
});

let elements = $(el).find('.myclass'); // Empty (length 0)
```

Nothing is output from the above loop from neither approaches.

I have tried all of the Angular2 lifecycle hooks that I found relevant, e.g. `AfterViewInit` and `AfterContentInit`. I have even tried to wrap the code within a DOM ready function in jQuery like so: `$(function() { ... });` - no difference.

As far as I can understand, the problem is that at the moment my code runs, my component's markup/template has not been added to the browser's DOM. I reached this conclusion for two reasons; firstly, if I add a timeout around the code, it works as long as the timeout is long enough. Secondly, if I output the elements to Chrome's console, everything looks OK, but I believe this is because when I inspect it in the console, the referenced value has been updated, because it is an object - and when the code ran, no elements were there. Perhaps I am wrong, but this is what I came up with anyways.

So the lifecycle hooks don't seem to do me any good in this case, neither does the DOM ready callback. I have looked around for similar questions, but haven't found anything that helped/worked.

To summarize, I need to find elements with a given class from *within my component* (within the component's template) when the component has been loaded. How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

I am using Angular2 RC4.

Comment: Most of the time, trying to access the DOM, especially all the elements in the document, is a bad idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet You are absolutely right, and I would also have preferred to solve it somehow else. I am using a JavaScript library (Dropzone.js) to enable file uploads in drop zones added within my template. Dropzone works on element IDs (you must supply an element ID when instantiating a drop zone), so basically I am trying to find elements with the `dropzone` class and feed their IDs to Dropzone. I am generating element IDs automatically for them to be unique, so I _can_ do a workaround and avoid accessing the DOM if necessary.

Comment: @BlažZupančič I tried - please see the code in the question.

Comment: The documentation says that *If you create your Dropzones with the normal constructor though, you have to pass either the raw HTMLElement, or a selector string*, so you should be able to just create a Dropzone component, get the host element, and pass it to the Dropzone constructor.

Comment: True, that should be possible. Thanks!